# Can't convert type: value: java.sql.Timestamp to org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

During persist time - all is ok, but when I try to execute next query I will have exception

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createSQLQuery("Select * From QUOTE").addScalar("id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
        .addScalar("date", StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP)  <-- this throw exception
        .addScalar("interval", myEnumType)
        .addScalar("open", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
        .addScalar("high", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
        .addScalar("low", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
        .addScalar("close", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
        .addScalar("volume", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(QuoteEntity.class));

    return query.list();
```

after execute I get error:

```
2015-11-20 14:03:08 ERROR BasicPropertyAccessor:121 - HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.usanin.financedata.entity.QuoteEntity, setter method of property: date
2015-11-20 14:03:08 ERROR BasicPropertyAccessor:122 - HHH000091: Expected type: org.joda.time.DateTime, actual value: java.sql.Timestamp
IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.usanin.financedata.entity.QuoteEntity.date (expected type = org.joda.time.DateTime)]; target = [com.usanin.financedata.entity.QuoteEntity@7cf3b5ad], property value = [2015-11-11 10:01:00.0]
```

Also I have: Hibernate - 4.3.11.Final, and org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA

and I ajusted in my

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    .....
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
     <props>
      <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
        ...
```

and entity

```
...
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
...

@Entity
@Table (name="QUOTE")
public class QuoteEntity {

    @Column
    private DateTime date;

... getters and setters
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I have chosen to use entity query like this:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery("Select * From QUOTE")
                .addEntity(QuoteEntity.class);

return query.list();
```

because, behavior of non-managed entity is very weird